# How to extract first part of filenames with same suffix?

Tags: sed, filenames, cut

I want to get at the prefix of a variable-length filename.

```
In: some_filename_123-uniq.tar.gz
Out: some_filename_123
In: some_filename_1-uniq.tar.gz
Out: some_filename_1
```

This does the exact opposite of what I want, `-uniq.tar.gz`:

```
result=$(echo *-uniq.tar.gz | rev | cut -c-12 | rev)
echo $result
```

There will only ever be one `-uniq.tar.gz` suffixed item.

I attempted using parameter substitution which seemed like the easiest way to go but get syntax errors:

```
${"some_filename_123-uniq.tar.gz"//"-uniq.tar.gz"}
bash: ${"some_filename_123-uniq.tar.gz"/""/"-uniq.tar.gz"}: bad substitution
```

Comment: Do you want to specifically solve the problem with *sed* or do you allow the use of other programs commonly available when working with the shell? If you allow for other programs have a look at *basename*: `basename some_filename_123-uniq.tar.gz .tar.gz`.

Comment: You can not do substitution on strings. You can use variable: `x="foobar"; echo ${x//bar}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I attempted using parameter substitution which seemed like the easiest
>   way to go

It *is* the easiest way to go (just keep in mind that, as the name suggests - and as pointed out in a comment, the shell *expands a parameter/variable* );
use `${var%-*}` to (reluctantly) remove suffix (in this case starting from the last `-`):

```
for f in ./*-uniq.tar.gz
do
printf %s\\n "${f%-*}"   
done
```

or `${var:offset:length}` to remove the last *N* characters (where *length* is a negative integer):

```
for f in ./*-uniq.tar.gz
do
printf %s\\n "${f:0:-12}"
done
```

Comment: One note: the `${var:offset:length}` form does not appear in the POSIX description of the [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) and is therefore – useful as it may be – to be considered less portable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick and dirty way, just use sed to replace that string with nothing (remove):

```
for i in *-uniq.tar.gz
do
result=$(echo $i | sed 's/-uniq.tar.gz$//')
echo "$result"
done
```

The above will go through a directory looking for anything ending in -uniq.tar.gz and then echo the result after it removes the end portion.

Comment: I do not understand the need for `/g` in the *sed* substitution command – is there some? Also I suggest to bind the *regex* to the end of the to be matched filename string with "$": `sed 's/-uniq.tar.gz$//'`

Comment: No, I suppose the global is not necessary and binding the regex is a good idea. Updated my response for that.